# WebGL 3D component does not display when used in tabs, modals, etc; (three.js)

Tags: three.js, webgl

I am trying to use viewstl.com plugin in my website. It works great but when I try to render the canvas inside a bootstrap tab or modal then it does not show.

Below is the warning I get in console log.

> GL_INVALID_VALUE : glViewport: negative width/height

Plugin can be check in this site https://www.viewstl.com/plugin/

I want to view the stl files even when they are rendered in bootstrap tabs and modals.

Comment: Sounds like the CSS is bad for whatever container div you're telling the library to render into.

Comment: Do you have a live example? It looks like the canvas has a width or height of less than 0, so it can't display anything.

Comment: @Pranay Mishra, Do you find the solution for this?

Comment: I am replying late but the solution is to open a new tab using js or jquery by changing classes. Hope this helps to others.